# Unsupervised Learning: Distinguishing 10 spoken numbers in Arabic

Tags: machine-learning, python

I want to develop an unsupervised learning method to identify spoken numbers in Arabic. My dataset consists of MFCC arrays. Every row consists of an array of shape(41,13), The row consists of float values. Originally, they're WAV files converted to MFCC values. Every row is a spoken number in Arabic, the numbers 0 to 9.

We don't have labels and want to cluster every row so that we end up with 10 clusters, which we can label afterwards.

Does anyone know if were heading in the right way or could you suggest a learning method that's suitable for this research?

Comment: Even if your clustering algorithm works, someone would have to go through all the samples and manually check if they are assigned correct "labels", so in the end, the amount of work would be similar to manually labelling them. If you didn't check them, you'll end up with low quality data, it is often the biggest bottleneck in terms of model performance. So the best you can do is to manually label the data, if you can, use 3+ labellers and take majority vote, since people make errors as well.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning - if you've really too many samples to manually label all of them.